# Run excel macro when cutcopymode is set to true

Tags: excel, private-methods, vba

I have a problem, I need a specific macro to run, whenever the `cutcopymode` is turned on, I mean I'll select some cells, and when I press `Ctrl+c` or `Ctrl+x` the macro `test1` must run, I've tried this but nothing happens.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Or Application.CutCopyMode = xlCut Then test1

End Sub
```

Comment: try changing `xlCopy` to `1` and `xlCut` to `2`, just tested, worked fine for me

Comment: tried to do that and for me it didn't worked @Raugmor

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "^x", "YourSub"
Application.OnKey "^c", "YourSub"
End Sub
```

Put this on your **ThisWorkbook** module. It will call your macro named"YourSub".
Further info on e.g.
http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/1981.html
You're welcome.

Comment: It will call your macro named "YourSub" every time the Ctrl+X or Ctrl+C combos are used. For further annoying your client I recommend disabling the right click as well.

Comment: Get creative. As a start I'd recommend changing "YourSub" to "test1". If you've done that I recommend closing then opening the workbook. You may want to read my source, they have other instances calling these methods too.

Comment: i did changed yoursub for test1 and nothing happens, closed the workbook also, i understood what happens in your code it should be working, but it isent =/